# unable to use ganach-cli in linux

Tags: solidity, blockchain, ganache

I have installed ganache-cli using command "yarn global add ganache-cli", but when i am running the command "ganache --version" the output is, "ganache-cli: command not found"

Comment: What is your linux version? Ubuntu, Fedora, Archlinux. Did you try using npm?

Comment: ubuntu version is 20.04, but i tried installing as root user using "npm install -g -ganache-cli" and it worked, thank you for responding though.